# How to sort dates that are in tuples in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, date-sorting

I am trying to sort a dictionary of tuples where the second item contains the dates to be sorted. 
The dictionary looks something like this:

```
time_founded: {Soonr: 2005-5-1, SpePharm: 2006-9-1, and so on...}
```

Right now I am trying to sort the dates like this:

```
dict = sortedLists[category]    
sortedtime = sorted(dict.iteritems(),  key=lambda  d: map(int, d.split('-')))
```

But I am getting an error because it is trying to sort the tuples (Soonr: 2005-5-1) instead of just the date.
How can I update the sorting parameters to tell it to only look at the date on not the whole tuple?

Comment: That doesn't look like a `dict` of `tuple` to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sortedtime = sorted(dict.iteritems(), key=lambda d: map(int, d[1].split('-')))
```

The only difference is the `[1]` which selects out the value portion of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have control over the data structure, but if you do, please change the first element of the data structure to be the date you need to sort by. Python sorts iterables by the first element it finds, or, it can sort by [a key you define](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

I'd recommend you make it a tuple, with a dictionary *in it*, to simplify things:

```
>>> dates = [ ('2006-9-1', {Soonr:'2005-5-1'}),
              ('2006-8-9', {Soonr:'2005-8-28'})
            ]
>>> dates.sort() #will sort by the first element of the list items, if iterable...
>>> dates
[('2006-8-9', {Soonr:'2005-8-28'}), ('2006-9-1', {Soonr:'2005-5-1'})]
```